# Use a button to remove data from a different sheet,

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure how to even put this into words. I know what i want to do in my head so hope this makes sense.

I have a an excel spreadsheet with 3 sheets.

**SHEET 1**

[image: Sheet 1]
.

Sheet 1 is pulling data from sheet 2 (cards) and sheet 3(employees)

A5: `=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2,Cards!A1:D11,1,FALSE)`

B5: `=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!C1,Employees!A2:D11,2,FALSE)`

**SHEET 2 (CARDS)**

[image]
.

**SHEET 3 (EMPLOYEES (i realise the names dont match, its just for testing))**

[image]

What i would like to do is click the remove button and the Employee ID be removed from the cards table that corresponds to the value in Sheet1: A6

im unsure how to say.. remove Employee ID from cards!D?? from the row that contains sheet1!A6

If anyone can help with that it would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think I have an idea as to what you are looking for, however before developing anything, can you confirm why you are looking to remove the employee ids?

Comment: its for keeping track of securtiy passes. An employee might lose their pass so i need to remove them from the card number.. or they may leave.. i'll eventually need an Add but if i can get the remove i may be able to figure the rest out myself....but for example.. john might have 12345 and he might leave so i need to remove it from john.. sarah will join the company so i can then bring up 12345 and add her to it.... she might lose pass 12345 so i need to then remove her and put her on another pass.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make a column for VALID / INVALID?

Comment: Theyre going to want me to report on things like who has had the pass in the past, show me all void passes, show me all passes with an employee.. show me all unsued passes etc.. I wanted to do an intranet DB and php kinda style which i have setup and kind of working but they want it in excel automated. :(

Comment: and my vba just crashed and there is no recovery. starting again.

Comment: In your example, all of those employee ids will be removed

Comment: hmm. intersting.. maybe i need to re think this.

Comment: Use  adodb. You can do it like  intranet DB and php kinda style.

Comment: would love ot but, they, being the big bosses, want it in excel. They already want a bunch of stuff outside my pay grade and we been like no, go pay someone.. but the rest we will try.. ive got some of it working now.